# How to arrange / align / place pictures and text, to form a given headline?

Tags: tables, graphics, positioning, minipage

I tried to solve this with tables, but the alignment didn't turn out good. And because I am very confused, if I should even use a table aproach or a minipage or a tabspace, I wondered, if someone could enlighten me, based on a specific demo.

This should be a regular task for anybody who has to create corporate or other official documents - creating a headline with logos and text, like here:

[image]

But how to accomplish this in Latex - the best way possible?

There are some requirements, like:

- has to span over entire page
- individual vertical and horizontal alignment is possible

These are some of my attemps, which did not work out:

With tables:

```
\documentclass[
    pdftex,
    a4paper,
    11pt,
    DIV15,
    BCOR20mm,
    parskip,
    numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
    \usepackage{graphics} 
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \noindent\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\stretch{1}}}*{2}{l}@{}}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{left_demo.png} & \includegraphics[height=45px]{right_demo.png} \\
    \end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

With minipage:

```
\documentclass[
pdftex,
a4paper,
11pt,
DIV15,
BCOR20mm,
parskip,
numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphics} 
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \begin{minipage}[b]{25mm}
            \includegraphics[width=25mm,clip]{left_demo.png}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[b]{12 cm}
            {\sffamily              
                somedemo txt abcdefghij,\\
                texttextte txt texttexttextetscter\\
                demodemode demodemode\\
            }
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

These are the demo-pictures I used:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

I scaled to make them all the same height, also the centre one is centred in the text area not centred between the two images (remove the `\rlap` and `\llap` if you want the latter).:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\rlap{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{left_demo.png}}
\hfill
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{center_demo.png}
\hfill
\llap{%
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}             
                somedemo txt abcdefghij,\\
                texttextte txt texttexttextetscter\\
                demodemode demodemode
\end{tabular}%
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{right_demo.png}}

\noindent X=\dotfill text \dotfill X

\noindent X=\dotfill text \dotfill X


\end{document}
```

Comment: ok that is very much nicer, then what I had until now, but would you please explain some parts? Why use tabular only for the text? would it be possible to adjust the images vertically, without scaling to the same heigth? As you can see, the actual logo in the left image is sourrounded by white(grey)space, I cannot change that, due to corporate instructions, so I would have to use eighter replicate this space to all the images or I would have to adjust their vertical position - the latter is what interests me. Any ideas?!

Comment: sorry I didn't see this comment, must have missed the alert for some reason. But I see you have found raisebox now. Feel free to accept your own answer which will mark this question as done.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @DavidCarlisle. Based on your post and after I read some other about `raisebox` and `parbox`, I camed up with this solution, which fits my need quite good for now.

```
\documentclass[
    pdftex,
    a4paper,
    11pt,
    DIV15,
    BCOR20mm,
    parskip,
    numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
    \usepackage{graphics} 
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \textsf{
    \begin{singlespace}
        \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\rlap{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{images/left_demo.png}}}
        \hfill
        %\includegraphics[height=60px]{center_demo.png}
        %\hfill
        \raisebox{-0.15\height}{\llap{
        \scriptsize %
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}r@{}}
              somedemo txt abcdefghij,\\
              texttextte txt texttexttextetscter\\
              demodemode demodemode
        \end{tabular}}}
        \raisebox{-0.525\height}{\includegraphics[height=45px]{right_demo.png}}
    \end{singlespace}}
\end{document}
```