# How to set this content into the header properly, when ihead & markright did not work well / at all

Tags: header-footer

After creating my headline here [How to arrange / align / place pictures and text, to form a given headline?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75285/how-to-arrange-align-place-pictures-and-text-to-form-a-given-headline) I guessed, I would just place it into the header with `\ihead` and `\thispagestyle{scrheadings}` - but NO.

Problem is, the following text is placed uppon my header. And when I try to use `markright` I get eighter compile errors or no header at all.

I read some infos about using `\protect`, but it did not help eighter. I am guessing, that my constuct itself is simply not that easy to migrate into a header. I hope I can solve this on my own, but maybe someone else seeks a challange too :)

Here is the code, the images to it are available through the link before:

```
\documentclass[
    pdftex,
    a4paper,
    11pt,
    DIV15,
    BCOR20mm,
    parskip,
    numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
    \usepackage{graphics} 
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
    \usepackage{scrpage2}
    \usepackage{setspace} 
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{scrheadings}
        \noindent
       \ihead{
        \textsf{
        \begin{singlespace}
             \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\rlap{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{left_demo.png}}}
            \hfill
            %\includegraphics[height=60px]{center_demo.png}
            %\hfill
            \raisebox{-0.15\height}{\llap{
            \scriptsize %
            \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}r@{}}
                  somedemo txt abcdefghij,\\
                  texttextte txt texttexttextetscter\\
                  \\
                  demodemode demodemode
            \end{tabular}}}
            \raisebox{-0.525\height}{\includegraphics[height=45px]{right_demo.png}}
        \end{singlespace}}}
        \huge{text}
\end{document}
```

I do really appreciate any help on this, thanks!

*Edit:*

Here is what's wrong:

[image]

the `text` in the red circle should not be that high (used `ihead` here)

Comment: your MWE runs without error, where were you planning to use marks?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand ... I tried using `\markright` instead of `\ihead`, but this gives me error `\KV@def has extra }` - using `\ihead` works fine - just the `\huge{text}` is placed too high

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do actually (\markright typically just takes simple text such as a section title the complicate layout would normally be part of the page head design but that it _uses_ the text from `\markright` where appropriate. That said if you want to stick the whole lot in a mark it appears to work to remove `\noindent` (which looks to be there in error ) and replace `\ihead` by        `\markright{\unexpanded{{` and add an extra `}` after `\end{singlespace}}}`

Comment: after `\end{singlespace}`? actually I would like to have the whole singlespace section to be IN the header. The `\huge{text}` is what I want to have beneath my header.

Comment: yes that's what the above comment would do, although as I say using a \mark isn't really the way to do it it (I'd say the basic latex way of setting up page headers but I think the script classes have their own mechanisms so perhaps some who has used those before might answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your images take more vertical spacing than the default vertical space reserved for the header. When you process your code you will get a warning like this:

```
Overfull \vbox (57.3689pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
```

(the actual value for the overfull box will depend on the actual images). The value for `\headheight` has to be increased accordingly to prevent the warning and you can do this using `headlines=` or `headheight=` (this probably implies a change in the page layout).

Here's a little example. From the comments it's clear that the intent is to change the page style for the `titlepage`; one possibility to achieve this is to define a new page style and to use the `geometry` package to temporarily change the `headheight` value without modifications to the page layout made as class options through `DIV` and `BCORR` (adjust the length according to your needs); since the contents of the footer for this style was not specified I used some dummy options in the definition of the new page style:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,a4paper,11pt,DIV15,BCOR20mm,parskip,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\defpagestyle{mystyle}{%
\ihead{\sffamily%
  \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\rlap{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{cat}}}\hfill
            %\includegraphics[height=60px]{center_demo.png}
            %\hfill
 \raisebox{-0.15\height}{\llap{%
    \scriptsize %
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}r@{}}
    somedemo txt abcdefghij,\\
    texttextte txt texttexttextetscter\\
    \\
    demodemode demodemode
    \end{tabular}}}
  \raisebox{-0.525\height}{\includegraphics[height=45px]{cat}}
 }
}{\ifoot{inside}\cfoot{center}\ofoot{outside}}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\thispagestyle{mystyle}
\newgeometry{headheight=45pt}
{\huge text} 
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{titlepage}

\clearpage
\restoregeometry

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Not relevant to the problem mentioned, but the font size switches (`\Huge`, `\huge`, `\LARGE`, etc.) are declarations that do not have arguments, so instead of `\huge{text}`, you should use `{\huge text}` (to keep the change local and possibly using `\par` inside the group if required).

Comment: yeah! this is it - but would you be so kind to extend your demo to adjust the healines just for a single page (e.g. titlepage) and how to avoid getting pagenumbering on this page, when using `ihead` - which is a strange behaviour anyways.

Comment: @Jook I have a lecture starting in 8 minutes, so I won't be able to give the modified example for several hours. As soon as I can I will do it.

Comment: thank you very much! I got rid of the pagenumbering by using `\ofoot{}` but this was accompanied by my bottom text beeing displayed too far down. And besides, I would like to use a footer on the titlepage - just without pagenumbering.

Comment: @Jook I updated my answer with the announced code.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my particular problem. However, in order to understand your code better, I started to read about geometry and pagestyles and stuff und must conclude - Latex has a quite some huge steps in it's learing curve, which one has to conquer.